# Crear una intro en mi web html

Tags: javascript, html, css

estoy creando mi portfolio personal, y tengo una idea en mente, que es al entrar a la web, salga algo tal y como muestro en el siguiente codigo:

```js
// const splash = document.querySelector('.splash');

// document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e)=> {
//     setTimeout(()=>{
//         splash.classList.add('display-none');
//     }, 2000);
// })
```

```css
/* Google Fonts */
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anonymous+Pro);

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  
    user-select: none;
  }
  
  body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
  
    display: inline;
  
    font-family: 'Anonymous Pro', monospace;

    background-color: rgb(67, 67, 67);
  }
  /* Intro */
  
  .splash {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 200;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  }

  /* .splash.display-none{
    position: fixed;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: -10;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  } */

  .line {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    width: 16em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-right: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    font-size: 180%;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

/* Animation */

.anim-typewriter {
  animation: typewriter 4s steps(40) 1s 1 normal both,
  blinkTextCursor 500ms steps(40) infinite normal;
}

@keyframes typewriter {
  from {
      width: 0;
  }
  to {
      width: 16em;
  }
  
}

/* @keyframes blinkTextCursor {
  from {
      border-right-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  }
  to {
      border-right-color: transparent;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  to {
      opacity: 1;
  }
  
} */

.fade-in {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in forwards;
}

  /* window frame */
  .window-frame {
    margin: 20% 10%;
    overflow: hidden;
  
    background-color: rgb(253, 249, 252);
    box-shadow: 0 1rem 4rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border: solid 0.1rem rgba(110, 110, 110, 0.5);
  
    border-radius: 1rem;
  }
  
  /* title bar */
  .title-bar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  
    background-color: rgb(232, 228, 229);
    border-bottom: solid 0.14rem rgb(224, 224, 224);
  
    padding: 0.6rem 1rem;
  }
  
  .dots {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .dots span {
    height: 1rem;
    width: 1rem;
    margin-left: 0.6rem;
  
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: solid 0.14rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
  
  .dots span:nth-child(1) { background-color: #14ca3a;}
  .dots span:nth-child(2) { background-color: #ffbf01;}
  .dots span:nth-child(3) { background-color: #fe6152;}
  
  /* window body */
  .window-body {
    padding: 6rem 10rem;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src='main.js'></script>
  <title>Document</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="splash">
    <p class="line anim-typewriter">Bienvenido a mi web</p>
  </div>

 
  <div class="window-frame">
    <div class="title-bar">
      <span>window.exe</span>
      <div class="dots">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="window-body">
      <h1>Prueba</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( ".window-frame" ).draggable({
      cancel: '.window-body'
    });
  } );
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

El problema, viene en que yo quiero que en cuanto termine de escribir el mensaje, haga un fade, y deje ver la otra parte que tengo de la web.
He probado con el código que tengo comentado, y añadiendo en el html la class nueva que creo que es la de "fade-in".
Pero cuando la meto al parrafo , el efecto de escritura se quita, y aun asi no desaparece y deja ver la siguiente parte de la web.

Answer (score 2):

```js
let splash = document.getElementById( 'spl' );
document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
     setTimeout( () => {
         setInterval( hide, 200 );
     }, 5000 );
 })
 
var opacity = 0;
var intervalID = 0;

function hide() {
    opacity = Number( window.getComputedStyle( splash ).getPropertyValue( "opacity" ))
    if( opacity > 0 ) {
        opacity = opacity -0.1;
        splash.style.opacity = opacity;
    }
    else{
        clearInterval( intervalID );
    }
}
```

```css
/* Google Fonts */
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anonymous+Pro);

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;      
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;      
    user-select: none;
  }
  
  body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;      
    display: inline;      
    font-family: 'Anonymous Pro', monospace;
    background-color: rgb(67, 67, 67);
  }
  /* Intro */
  
  .splash {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 200;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  }

  .line {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    width: 16em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-right: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    font-size: 180%;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

/* Animation */

.anim-typewriter {
  animation: typewriter 4s steps(40) 1s 1 normal both,
  blinkTextCursor 500ms steps(40) infinite normal;
}

@keyframes typewriter {
  from {
      width: 0;
  }
  to {
      width: 16em;
  }
  
}

/* @keyframes blinkTextCursor {
  from {
      border-right-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  }
  to {
      border-right-color: transparent;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  to {
      opacity: 1;
  }
  
} */



  /* window frame */
  .window-frame {
    margin: 20% 10%;
    overflow: hidden;
  
    background-color: rgb(253, 249, 252);
    box-shadow: 0 1rem 4rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border: solid 0.1rem rgba(110, 110, 110, 0.5);
  
    border-radius: 1rem;
  }
  
  /* title bar */
  .title-bar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  
    background-color: rgb(232, 228, 229);
    border-bottom: solid 0.14rem rgb(224, 224, 224);
  
    padding: 0.6rem 1rem;
  }
  
  .dots {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .dots span {
    height: 1rem;
    width: 1rem;
    margin-left: 0.6rem;
  
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: solid 0.14rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
  
  .dots span:nth-child(1) { background-color: #14ca3a;}
  .dots span:nth-child(2) { background-color: #ffbf01;}
  .dots span:nth-child(3) { background-color: #fe6152;}
  
  /* window body */
  .window-body {
    padding: 6rem 10rem;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src='main.js'></script>
  <title>Document</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="splash" id="spl">
    <p class="line anim-typewriter">Bienvenido a mi web</p>
  </div>

 
  <div class="window-frame">
    <div class="title-bar">
      <span>window.exe</span>
      <div class="dots">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="window-body">
      <h1>Prueba</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( ".window-frame" ).draggable({
      cancel: '.window-body'
    });
  } );
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Perdón por la primer respuesta, no entendí bien tu pedido.
Como podés ver, le asigné una `id` al `div`, para no tener problemas, con la misma función que creaste, llamo a **`hide`**, que carga en **`opacity`**, el valor actual de opacidad, luego en el `if`, si esta es mayor que cero, le resta `0.1`, y lo aplica al `div`.
Cuando **`opacity`** es cero, entra en el else, y limpia el intervalo.

Comment: La explicación, no te olvides de la explicación :-)

Comment: @Cris223511.dev, lo bueno de estar rodeado de maestros, es que me puedo equivocar tranquilo, que siempre me ayudarán a corregir, gracias de nuevo!!! (aunque la explicación me salió, medio "flojita").

Comment: No hay de que, para eso estamos!!

Comment: @MarcePuente Y sabes porque ese codigo probandolo en visual studio code y ejecutandolo en mi pc, no funciona.
Pero si lo meto aqui tal cual copiado de mi codigo si ?